# iOS: Control two CheckBoxes

Tags: objective-c, ios, checkbox, uibutton, sender

I have this code to control two check boxes (buttons customized):

```
- (IBAction) setCheckBox: (id) sender{

    UIImage *selected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"];
    UIImage *notSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"];

    if ([sender isSelected]) 
    {  
        [sender setImage:notSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
        [sender setSelected:NO];  
        if ([sender tag] == 10) boolOne = FALSE;
        if ([sender tag] == 11) boolTwo = FALSE;
    }
    else 
    {     
        [sender setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateSelected]; 
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        if ([sender tag] == 10) boolOne = TRUE;
        if ([sender tag] == 11) boolTwo = TRUE;
    }
}
```

You can see that this code control two checkboxes, when I press one it become checked and when I press another time it become unchecked.

Now I want change this code in this way:
In default checkbox with tag 10 is checked and when I press it, I haven't effects, but when I press checkbox with tag 11 it should be checked and checkbox 10 should be unchecked.
The checkbox should toggle the selection and also the bool value

Comment: what is your main problem? where are you stuck at?

Comment: I want to checkboxes, that when I press one it become checked other checkbox become unchecked, only this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if([sender isSelected])
 return;
if([sender tag] == 11){
  [sender setSelected:YES];
 [checkbox10 setSelected:NO];
}
if ([sender tag] == 10) {
 [sender setSelected:YES];
 [checkbox11 setSelected:NO];
}
```

you can get checkbox by tag value like I assume checkbox are instance of uibutton so

```
UIButton *checkBox10 = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:10];
```

I hope you understand. Also set the images according to code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the behavior of radio buttons, you should probably use radio buttons instead of check boxes.

Assuming that you store your check boxes as instance variables named `checkbox10` and `checkbox11`, this should solve your problem:

```
- (IBAction) setCheckBox: (id) sender{

    UIImage *selected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"];
    UIImage *notSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"];

    if (![sender isSelected]) 
    {  
        [sender setImage:notSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        if ([sender tag] == 10)
        {
            boolOne = YES;
            boolTwo = NO;
            [checkbox11 setImage:notSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
            [checkbox11 setSelected:NO];
        }
        if ([sender tag] == 11)
        {
            boolTwo = YES;
            boolOne = NO;
            [checkbox10 setImage:notSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
            [checkbox10 setSelected:NO];
        }
    }
}
```